# Undo copy (cp) command action

Tags: command-line, cp

I copied some file from source folder into destination folder by using bellow command line in terminal.

```
sudo cp From_SOURCE/* To_DESTINATION/
```

Now I want to undo this command.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Simply remove the copy? (sudo rm file)

Comment: @JacobVlijm it's not undo action it's a separate command. If I didn't copy so I could use your suggested command previously. And I have to more and more time use this command to delete more than 1000 files copied?

Comment: @KasiyA - a option would be to find all the filenames that were selected from `From_SOURCE/*`, and remove those from `To_DESTINATION/`; this could be done with bash - the problems here could include cp command overwrote anything, symlinks were copied, files with spaces in names, etc - so it could have issues and go a bit wacky. A perfect 'undo' option could would have to account for lots of stuff.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand well, the following is the case:

- You copied a (presumably large) number of files on to an existing directory, and you need / want to reverse the action.
- The targeted directory contains a number of *other* files, that you need to keep there, which makes it impossible to simply remove *all* files from the directory

The script below looks in the original (source) directory and lists those files. Then it looks into the directory you copied the files to, and removes only the listed files, as they exist in the source directory.

The `try` element is added to prevent errors, for example in case you might have removed some files manually already, or if not all files from the source directory were copied to the destination. If you need sudo privileges, simply run the script with "sudo" (see below).

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

source_dir = "/path/to/source" # the folder you copied the files from
target_folder = "/path/to/destination" # the folder you copied the files to

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
    for name in files:
        try:
            os.remove(target_folder+"/"+name)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass
```

#### How to use

- Paste the script in an empty file, save it as `reverse.py`,
- Insert the correct paths for source and target folder,
- Make it executable for convenience reasons,
- Run it by the command:

  ```
  [sudo] /path/to/reverse.py
  ```

#### Warning

First try on a test directory if I understood well what you need to achieve!

---

#### If the sourcedirectory is "flat"

In case the source directory has no sub-directories, the script can even be simpler:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

source_dir = "/path/to/source" # the folder you copied the files from
target_folder = "/path/to/destination" # the folder you copied the files to

for file in os.listdir(source_dir):
    try:
        os.remove(target_folder+"/"+file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

**Note**

If the copy action *overwrote* (replaced) a similarly named file in the destination, the file will be removed, but the original file will (of course) not be brought back by the script. The assumption is that there are no name clashes.

Comment: It works, thank you. I run it by `sudo python3 reverse.py`. I accept your answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for a nice question, which describes a situation we've probably all been in :)

Comment: Note: If any file in the source *overwrote* a file in the destination because it had the same name, then you cannot simply un-do it, and this script will just delete it.  The assumption here is that there were no name clashes when you did the initial `cp`.

Comment: @neon_overload Correct, edited it in my answer.

Comment: This does not work for `cp -r`. I changed `os.remove` with `print`, and it's outputting a bunch of files that does not exist. I'm assuming it's missing the subdirectories, and only listing the files at the end.

Answer (score 8):

### TL;DR:

All files that are present in both `src` and `dest` can be removed from `dest` like this:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' "$destdir/{}" \; -exec mv -n "$destdir/{}" "$toDelete"/ \;
```

For a step-by-step, explanation, see below.

### Simplifying the problem:

To understand what the command we want to undo actually did, we start by simpifying it:

The command we want to undo is

```sh
sudo cp From_SOURCE/* To_DESTINATION/
```

For understanding how to undo, `sudo` is not relevant.

I'll use the directory names `src` for `From_SOURCE` and `dest` for `To_DESTINATION`.

Now, our command is:

```sh
cp src/* dest/
```

If `src` contains the files `f1`, `f2` and `f3`, and the directories `d1` and `d2`, the shell expands that command to:

```sh
cp src/f1 src/f2 src/f3 src/d1 src/d2 dest/
```

Without options like `-r`, `-R` or `-a`, the command `cp` does not copy directories.
That means, the command will leave them out, showing an error for each of them:

```sh
$ cp src/f1 src/f2 src/f3 src/d1 src/d2 dest/
cp: omitting directory 'src/d1'
cp: omitting directory 'src/d2'
```

That means, we have only copied simple files, and no directories, to `dest`.

### Deciding which files to remove:

Possibly there were files in `dest` of the same name as files in `src`. In this case, the files were overwritten (1). It's too late for them, sorry. Get them back from the latest backup.

Regarding the files that are there, we want to remove only files that have been copied over. These files exist in both directories, with the same name, and the same content.

So we look for these files:

First, we `cd` into `src`, because it makes the following `find` commands much simpler, and set a variable to the absolute path of dest:

```sh
$ cd src
$ destdir="$(readlink -f dest)"
```

Then, we list all files in src:

```sh
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

and, for each file found, use `cmp` to check whether there is a file with the same content in dest:

```sh
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' "$destdir/{}" \; -print
```

### Removing the files, carefully:

These files are the ones we want to remove. But to be sure, we move them into a different directory first - and take a look at the commands before running them:

```sh
$ toDelete=/tmp/toDelete ; mkdir -p "$toDelete"
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' "$destdir/{}" \; -exec echo mv -n "$destdir/{}" "$toDelete"/ \;
mv -n /path/to/dest/./f1 /tmp/toDelete/`
mv -n /path/to/dest/./f2 /tmp/toDelete/`
mv -n /path/to/dest/./f3 /tmp/toDelete/`
```

Looks good! Now we can leave out the `echo` to run the real `mv` commands:

```sh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec cmp -s '{}' "$destdir/{}" \; -exec mv -n "$destdir/{}" "$toDelete"/ \;
```

All the files from `dest` that were copied from `src`, and still actually the same in `src` and `dest`, are now in `/tmp/toDelete/`, and can be removed after taking a last look.

---

Notes:
(1) Check whether `cp` is an alias to `cp -i` or so, that would have prevented overwriting files by asking first.

Answer (score 5):

This is old, but I just wanted to post a pure bash answer:

First change to the directory where you copied the files.

`cd dest`

Then, `ls` the source directory and pipe the output into `rm`

`ls source | xargs rm`

Comment: parsing `ls` is typically a bad idea. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs  I won't downvote your post, but it has to be noted.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy good point. Never the less: `rm \`ls\``—for an empty beforehand folder and when the files have names without spaces and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Code in the upvoted answer but it didn't work, probably because it was python.

I modified the code/script and could work in most directories, using python3. Of course all the warnings by @Jacob Vlijm apply to this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

source_dir = "path/to/folder/copied from" # the folder you copied the files from
target_folder = "path/to/destination/folder" # the folder you copied the files to

for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(source_dir):
    for name in files:
        source_file = root+"/"+name
        try:
            path_to_del = target_folder + source_file[len(source_dir):] #path to deletable file
            print(path_to_del)
            os.remove(path_to_del)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found, file Skipped")
            pass
```

Make sure to follow the remaining steps i.e. making the executeable

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer based on the timestamp of the copy operation.
You could list the folder contents in order of time of creation and pipe it to a file:

```
ls -alt | file_list
```

Then open `file_list` and find the files with the same timestamp of the copy operations. Presumably, these will be the latest files.

Then edit `file_list` to `rm -rf` the non-required files/folders and save it.

Then do:

```
source file_list
```